# Is there a way to filter a tags after I start parsing them with simple html dom

Tags: php

I build a script which extract a tags with simple html dom and parse them and collect some information and then send to a DB, but the problem is I have too many urls to parse and I'm asking if is optimal how I do, so right now my multi curl script extract source codes simultaneously and then find tags a with simple html dom and now I'm asking, is there a way to make it more optimal like I don't know to filter somehow a tags and THEN to parse them with simple html dom? For what I know simple html dom eat some resources to do that but if I filter somehow only the a tags from source code for each site maybe it will work better... any advice?

Comment: yes simple html dom is rather memory hungry, check out [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: did u say to use DOM instead simple html dom or to filter them with DOM and then to parse with simple html dom

Comment: just use DOM all the way through. no need to mix them both

Comment: ok, great, i have to test it, thanks